# Is there a word for getting excited about nothing?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word for getting excited about absolutely nothing? For example, if you can recall in the Christmas movie *ELF*, Buddy got all excited about wondering what a Christmas gram was. In reality, though, it isn't all that exciting. Is there a word for that?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Oops! I provided an answer, but then discovered this was a duplicate of something else—where my own answer, and alternate suggestions, already exist: **tempest in a teapot**, **make a mountain out of a molehill**, and **much ado about nothing**. (To be fair, I deleted my answer after marking the duplicate.) I can think of no single word for this.

Comment: @JasonBassford You have helped me in the past before! Thanks again for your help! =)